# Unable to import S/MIME certificate and key into my iPhone (iOS7)

Tags: ios, certificate

I tried to generate a S/MIME certificate from comodo.com. On my Mac it perfectly works. But I am unable to use it on iOS 7. This is what I did:

- generate certificate on Mac
- export certificate and private key in p12 format from keychain
- sent the p12 and the Comodo cert (COMODO Client Authentication and Secure Email CA.cer) via email to iphone
- import both certificates
- enable S/MIME in email client on iPhone

When I look into my Profiles (General > Profiles) I see the comodo certificate as TRUSTED (1) as well as my private cert (2) . But when I look into the S/MIME settings from the email account on iPhone it is NOT TRUSTED (3).

[image]
[image]
[image]

My emails got not signed / encrypted then.

What am I doing wrong? I am lost.

Comment: Seems this question is no longer relevant. I think I remember that restarting the mail app helped, but, as far as I know, this has been fixed in iOS 9 or so, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly I had a look into my certificate in the mail accounts section. It was untrusted. I then got into the section of profiles and had a look into the imported profile. It was trusted.

Then I went back to the certificate in the mail account section and it was trusted!

This seems all quite buggy, Apple.

Comment: agreed. its a bit annoying to have to manually trust each certificate for each user. OSX does it automatically.... but once its installed it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export your private key instead of your public key so that way your certificate in mail account section will be trusted.. That is common behavior when you import your public key instead of your private one..